# GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript for js.map

Tags: javascript, gulp, mapping

I'm getting this error when I run `gulp build`

```
GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc (:)
File: /root/newTheme/assets/js/maps/theme.js.map
Line: 1
Col: 10
```

I don't know what these means and what to look for.

How can I solve this or what do I need to provide more here?

`theme.js.map`;

https://pastebin.com/2PdeQXrk

`gulpfile.js`

https://pastebin.com/bX8SFsNX

Comment: Show us the code from `/root/newTheme/assets/js/maps/theme.js.map` or we can't help you.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here; https://pastebin.com/R910Pfri

Answer (score -1):

Can you show us your gulpfile.js, I would install gulp-sourcemaps to help you narrow down the error you are receiving.

Comment: Here's the `gulpfile.js` https://pastebin.com/bX8SFsNX I will give your advice a try